# what's wrong in this initialization

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to load uimage with image in path like this

/var/mobile/Applications/429E283A-6E89-4BCE-861F-252C5327F711/Library/Application Support/Students/43y.   F./1.2.840.113564.3.1.2.180.0.0.90.20081228203734483950/1.2.840.113564.10.1.226230117146661685815524478531105858244/Thumbnail.bmp

I used the following code

```
UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:ThumbnailPath];

if (theImage !=nil) {

        cell.imageView.image = theImage;

}
else {

    NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

where ThumbnailPath is the path 
but the uiimage always nil, and I am sure the file exists  , can any one please fix it for me

Best regards

Comment: try using this UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:Thumbnail.bmp];

Comment: it's in directory not in the main bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:ThumbnailPath];

if (theImage !=nil) {

        cell.imageView.image = theImage;

}
else {

    NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I dont thing UIImage imageNamed can load from .bmp files..Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350654/how-do-i-save-an-uiimage-as-bmp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755316/why-does-the-iphone-cgimagecreate-with-data-from-standard-bmp-bits-give-the-wrong) SO threads about handling .bmp files in iphone

Comment: It can according to the documentation: [UIImage Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Refer [UIImage class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for load image.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the value for "ThumbnailPath"
Are you using + pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory: method under NSBundle class.
If not consider using that. 
If yes please edit your question and include the part of your code where you set the value for ThumbnailPath.

Answer (score 0):

May Be this can help you

```
+(UIImage*)getImageFromDocumentDirectoryWithName:(NSString*)imageName
{
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *aPath= [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    UIImage *myimage=nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:aPath])
    {
        myimage =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:aPath];
    }

    return myimage;
}
```

You can use add this functon in desired class and use it accordingly